# Append audio file to videos

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, audio-conversion

I have the following files:

### 01.mp4

```
G:\>ffmpeg -i 01.mp4
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '01.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf54.63.104
  Duration: 00:14:21.42, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3746 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720, 3616 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(unk): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 123 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

### 02.mp4

```
G:\>ffmpeg -i 02.mp4    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '02.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2013-12-06 17:49:10
    encoder         : FAAC 1.26.1 (Apr 29 2008) UNSTABLE
  Duration: 00:01:21.75, start: 0.023220, bitrate: 120 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 119 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-12-06 17:49:10
```

### 03.mp4

```
G:\>ffmpeg -i 03.mp4
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '03.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4V
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: M4V M4A mp42isom
  Duration: 00:20:31.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1928 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 1796 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50k tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
```

I've to append the files `02.mp4` and `03.mp4` to `01.mp4`; such that, after the first video finishes (at **00:14:21.42**); the next file (only audio present, no video stream) would play (with *empty/white/black* background?). The audio duration is ~2 minutes after which the third file would start playing.

<sub>**PS**: Please do not suggest creating playlists. I want one mkv/mp4 file as a result. The file is to be distributed to several other people and telling everyone about the sequence etc. is irksome</sub>

I've played around with [MKVToolNix](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/) and [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) and managed to resize and merge the two video files (`01.mp4` and `03.mp4`); but I still have no idea how to proceed for inserting the audio stream with a blank video frame...

---

> ## FFmpeg information
>
> ```
> ffmpeg version N-58869-gae33007 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
>   built on Dec  7 2013 22:01:45 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
>   configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
> isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
> le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
> e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
> ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
> ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
> eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
> cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
> ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
>   libavutil      52. 56.100 / 52. 56.100
>   libavcodec     55. 45.100 / 55. 45.100
>   libavformat    55. 22.100 / 55. 22.100
>   libavdevice    55.  5.102 / 55.  5.102
>   libavfilter     3. 92.100 /  3. 92.100
>   libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
>   libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
>   libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
> ```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use lavfi input here, with filter color. Here is an example command:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.wav -f lavfi -i "color=black:size=1920x1080:duration=40" \
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v][3:v]concat=n=3[out_video];[0:a][1:a][2:a]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[out_audio]" \
-y -map [out_audio] -map [out_video] out.mp4
```

Where 1.mp4 and 2.mp4 are files with video, 3.wav is file with audio. Size of lavfi input should be the same as video size of 1.mp4 and 2.mp4. Duration of lavfi input should be the same as duration of 3.wav file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've started the process. I'll tell you the result as soon as it finishes.